# Update changes in a dataservice using visual basic connected to a database

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I am able to access the data I have on the database however I cannot update any of the changes I wish to make from the client side.

here is where I believe the problems are. (vb2010)

Server side -

```
Public Function UpdateData(ByVal ds As RecipesTitleDataset) As Integer

    Try

        Dim da As New RecipesTitleDatasetTableAdapters.RecipeTitlesTableAdapter()

        Dim nRows As Integer = da.Update(ds)

        Return nRows

    Catch ex As Exception

        Return 1

    End Try

End Function
```

Client side -

```
Private Sub btnUpdateRecord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
```

ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateData.Click

```
    Dim dsUpdates As DataSet = ds.GetChanges()

    If dsUpdates.HasChanges Then

        ds.Merge(ds, True)

        MessageBox.Show(Service.UpdateData(dsUpdates) & " CELLS CHANGED")

    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help.